# Group by fields in single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble with a query, have been stuck with it for a few days. It's not too complex but after trying and failing I've decided to post it here.

I have a table with 4 fields (`id | period | type | amount`). `period` has the last two digits from the year, and the two digits from month (values like 1512, 1601) and `type` is 1,2 or 3. What I'm trying to do is sum the `amount` field grouped by `period` and `type`, but the problem it's that I'm trying to do it with grouping `type` in one row. This will be easier to show with an example of data and desire output.

Data:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+--------+
| id    | period   | type      | amount |
+-------+----------+-----------+--------+
| 1     |  1511    | 1         | 15     |
| 2     |  1511    | 1         | 20     |
| 3     |  1511    | 2         | 15     |
| 4     |  1511    | 3         | 30     |
| 5     |  1512    | 1         | 20     |
| 6     |  1512    | 1         | 20     |
| 7     |  1512    | 2         | 35     |
| 8     |  1512    | 2         | 40     |
| 9     |  1512    | 2         | 45     |
| 10    |  1512    | 2         | 45     |
| 11    |  1512    | 3         | 15     |
| 12    |  1601    | 1         | 20     |
| 13    |  1601    | 2         | 25     |
| 14    |  1601    | 2         | 40     |
| 15    |  1601    | 3         | 60     |
| 16    |  1601    | 3         | 65     |
+-------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

Desire output:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| period  | type1  | type2  | type3  |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1511    | 35     | 15     | 30     |
| 1512    | 40     | 165    | 15     |
| 1601    | 20     | 65     | 125    |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

And what I have so far is this query, which shows one row for `type`, and not what I want:

```
SELECT period, type, sum(amount) FROM payments GROUP BY period, type;
```

Comment: the keyword you are searching for is called `pivot`. I will post an answer later

Comment: okey, will be waiting. Thank you Mr. mistery

Comment: Just use a case expression. `sum(case when type = 1 then amount else 0 end) as type1`

Comment: ok, saw that you are using `postgresql`. then the sql-keyword is `crosstab`

Comment: Thanks, I used shawnt00 expression and it worked perfectly.